Solve for variable f when f is in a denominator function of a sum
I have the following equation which I need to solve for f:
$\frac{X}{fY} = \sum_t^{T-1}\frac{A(t)}{f\cdot B(t)+1}$
While this seems very solvable, it has stumped an entire group of physics students. We have tried:

completing the square
polynomial long division
separating the functions into $\frac{A}{fB+1} = F(f)G(A,B)$ so that we could pull F(f) out of the sum.

None of which have been successful. Explicitely
$A(t) = p_t(kt-1)$
$B(t) = kt-1$
We also couldn't prove that there is no general solution. We have spend about 4 hours on this seemingly trivial problem and we're frustrated and all out of ideas.
Edit:
$p_t \in \mathbb{Q}\forall t$
$k \in \mathbb{Q}$

That may seem "very solvable" but it's not.
In the simple case when $A(t)= X = Y = 1$ and $B(t) = t$ it looks like
$$
\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{f+1} + \frac{1}{2f+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{(T-1)f+1}.
$$
If you multiply through to clear the denominators you see a polynomial of degree $T$ in $f$. There's no formula for that.
You don't even need the simplification to see that kind of polynomial.

well, numerical solution it is.

Sorry that's necessary. If the answer helps (albeit in an unsatisfactory way) you can accept it so the question does not remain on the unanswered queue.
